# Dynamically change models and controllers after publishing website in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC 2. I need to operator can change some elements of Models  or view codes. How I can code or design for it.

For example: I have a "news" model and I want to operator (final user of website, who can't code or access to visual studio) can add this to "news" model:

```
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

and also can change the database without coding.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately too broad for this forum. You'll have create an application that allows _authorized_ end users to create/read/update/delete (CRUD) persisted data (in some database). You'll find multiple resources for this at the [ASP.Net site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to design a completely extensible model, you could use something called Entity–attribute–value model (EAV).

Your model might have a couple common attributes like Title and Summary. Then you might have a list of Custom Fields, the first of which could be ImageUrl. You could create your own class called CustomField or something similar, which would have properties such as FieldName, and DataType.

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Summary { get; set; }
public List<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }
```

You would then have a table full of custom field values and the tables they belong to. It gets pretty complex.

Comment: Thanks Chris, My business logic is so complicated and it has so variety! what is your opinion to handle it. (for example: an operator how to handle a dependencies of two drop down list to each other like proviance and city?)

Comment: What I do in this situation is provide "first class support" for the most popular features, and custom fields for everything else. If the customer insists on cascading drop-downs, I'll provide that and use Country and State/Province drop-downs, where my countries are in one table and State/Provinces are in another pointing back to countries. International addresses can be very difficult and are a whole problem in itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to automatically reflect your model changes to the database, you will need an ORM framework like EF (Entity Framework). You can check more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

In order for your case to happen is to build your own configuration platform that may use several tools and mechanincs that will allow you to generate code and then compile it. Such as [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017) and more.

In general, this is a very hard task to accomplish and even big experienced teams would have troubles to build something similar.

I can not post any code, as this would only seem a desperate approach.

Comment: Thanks mtsiakiris,

Comment: Thanks mtsiakiris, 1- In your opinion, Can I change view dynamically based on the huge model (That have all needed data like all data-types and view options for Html5 tags ) ? Is it lead to slow pages?  2-  What's your idea for developing a fully dynamic Content Management System by .Net Core MVC?

Comment: Hi @A.M.Markid, nowadays there are so many CMS out there, that it is easier to use a ready-used-working-tested, rather than build it your own.

Comment: Hi @A.M.Markid, nowadays there are so many CMS out there, that it is easier to use a ready-used-working-tested, rather than build it your own.
In general, you can build anything you want with .net core 2 technology.
There is no barier for the moment you have designed well your solution starting with some wireframes, service definitions, blue printing, etc.
I strongly encourage you to use one of the most popular CMS out there and start building on top of it. The only disadvantage is that .net is not so popular for a CMS. Check DNN[link](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/), that is based on .net.

Comment: Thanks mtsiakiris, I worked with joomla, wordpress and some other free cms. but I haven't good experience with them. I have some customers with special needs. I try to write my own cms to support them. I need a specific design and modeling that wants at least coding for my employees. I hope your comments help me to design a perfect cms. (for example: my customers must be able to change all data and processes in their panels!). Are you know any similar project or cms? or Are you have any idea about it?